# Unable to re-purchase an app after reporting and getting refunded by Apple

Tags: mac-appstore

How do you buy an app on the Mac App Store that you purchased but asked for a refund from Apple? I purchased an app that I reported and got refunded for due to an issue, but the developer eventually fixed the problem in question.  I would like to purchase the app again.

I just have an **Update** button when I go to the app listing and I get the following error when I click on it.

```
This update is not available for this Apple ID either because it was bought by a different user or the item was refunded or cancelled.
```

I don't see any option to purchase the app again.

Comment: that sounds like a "call Apple Customer Service" issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is by design. This is likely to avoid potential gaming of the App Store where users purchase an app, ask Apple for a refund and continue using the app.

Apple disallowed to update or re-download refunded apps on both App Store for iOS and Mac App Store. While this may hurt genuine use cases like yours where an app update has potentially fixed the problem.

Both pros and cons of the approach has been discussed. A few articles are linked below:

- [Apple makes it impossible to get updates for refunded apps](https://www.cultofmac.com/280788/apple-makes-impossible-get-updates-refunded-apps/)
- [Apple now makes it clear you’re not allowed to update or redownload refunded apps](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/05/26/refunded-apps-changes/)

In case like yours, the recommended approach to take would be to [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) with Apple. It would also make sense to bring this to the developers attention.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.apple.com/emea/support/itunes/contact.html 
Contact iTunes support & write them down the exact thing you asked.//.  You will be helped.